# What can we do with doubloons

Tags: anno-online

In Anno-Online we can earn Doubloons with the new quests.
Can anyone say what we can use these for?

It matters, because the reward is given in the form of an item that results in a resource increase on a specific island. So you can only use the Doubloons on the island you activate the item on.

Answer (score 1):

[Doubloons were a commemorative currency for the 15th anniversary of Anno Onlin](http://forum.us.anno-online.com/threads/474-Ubi-Official-The-Annoversary-Event)e. Doubloons could be used to unlock new in-game content such as an enhanced marketplace, a scout's hideout, an old tree and an oriental ship.